# I want my script to give popup automatically after 3 hours? how can do it?

Tags: autoit

I have an autoit script which on double click it will show total time(for example from how many hours I am in office).now i want my script to give popup after 3 hours without my interaction .this is my script.

```
#include <Date.au3>

Global $ini = "ini.ini"

If _AlreadyRunToday() Then
   MsgBox (0, "Total hours", _Format(_Diff()))
Else
   __SetTime()
EndIf
__SetDate()


Func _AlreadyRunToday()
   If IniRead($ini, "Section", "D", "") <> @MDay _
      Or IniRead($ini, "Section", "M", "") <> @Mon _
      Or IniRead($ini, "Section", "Y", "") <> @Year Then Return False
   Return True
EndFunc

Func _ReadDate() ;Returns the time when the program run the first time in YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS
   Return IniRead($ini, "Section", "Y", "") & "/" & IniRead($ini, "Section", "M", "") & "/" & IniRead($ini, "Section", "D", "") & " " & IniRead($ini, "Section", "H", "") & ":" & IniRead($ini, "Section", "Mi", "") & ":" & IniRead($ini, "Section", "S", "")
EndFunc

Func __SetDate() ;Sets the date the program run the last time
   IniWrite($ini, "Section", "D", @MDay)
   IniWrite($ini, "Section", "M", @Mon)
   IniWrite($ini, "Section", "Y", @Year)
EndFunc

Func __SetTime() ;Sets the time of the first instance running that day
   IniWrite($ini, "Section", "H", @Hour)
   IniWrite($ini, "Section", "Mi", @Min)
   IniWrite($ini, "Section", "S", @Sec)
EndFunc

Func _Diff() ;Calculates the seconds passed since the first run today
   Return _DateDiff("s", _ReadDate(), _NowCalc())
EndFunc

Func _Format($Seconds)
   Local $h, $m, $s
   _TicksToTime($Seconds * 1000, $h, $m, $s)
   ;Return $h & ":" & $m & ":" & $s
   Return StringFormat("%02d:%02d:%02d", $h, $m, $s)
EndFunc
```

i want an idea about that.thank you.

Comment: You mean, you haven't started you script the last three hours? Or do you need a loop, which checks whether there were any key hits or mousemoves within the last 3 hours? Do you want to check your working time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.
It will notify you every 3 hours.

```
#include <Date.au3>

Global $ini = "ini.ini"


If _AlreadyRunToday() Then
   MsgBox (0, "Total hours", _Format(_Diff()))
Else
   __SetTime()
EndIf
__SetDate()



While True

    Sleep(3 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ; Sleep for 3 hours
    MsgBox (0, "Total hours", _Format(_Diff()), 60)

WEnd





Func _AlreadyRunToday()
   If IniRead($ini, "Section", "D", "") <> @MDay _
      Or IniRead($ini, "Section", "M", "") <> @Mon _
      Or IniRead($ini, "Section", "Y", "") <> @Year Then Return False
   Return True
EndFunc

Func _ReadDate() ;Returns the time when the program run the first time in YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS
   Return IniRead($ini, "Section", "Y", "") & "/" & IniRead($ini, "Section", "M", "") & "/" & IniRead($ini, "Section", "D", "") & " " & IniRead($ini, "Section", "H", "") & ":" & IniRead($ini, "Section", "Mi", "") & ":" & IniRead($ini, "Section", "S", "")
EndFunc

Func __SetDate() ;Sets the date the program run the last time
   IniWrite($ini, "Section", "D", @MDay)
   IniWrite($ini, "Section", "M", @Mon)
   IniWrite($ini, "Section", "Y", @Year)
EndFunc

Func __SetTime() ;Sets the time of the first instance running that day
   IniWrite($ini, "Section", "H", @Hour)
   IniWrite($ini, "Section", "Mi", @Min)
   IniWrite($ini, "Section", "S", @Sec)
EndFunc

Func _Diff() ;Calculates the seconds passed since the first run today
   Return _DateDiff("s", _ReadDate(), _NowCalc())
EndFunc

Func _Format($Seconds)
   Local $h, $m, $s
   _TicksToTime($Seconds * 1000, $h, $m, $s)
   ;Return $h & ":" & $m & ":" & $s
   Return StringFormat("%02d:%02d:%02d", $h, $m, $s)
EndFunc
```

Comment: it is working after three hours .But I asked it should give pop up by itself. I should not double click..

Comment: Script must be started in order for it to work lol.
Do you want it to start with windows?